# Are there third-party keyboards that have the Apple layout?

Tags: hardware-recommendation, keyboard, third-party

Apple keyboards are different than PC keyboard because the <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd> and <kbd>Option/Alt ⌥</kbd> keys are switched. This causes a workflow disruption for me, because I use keyboard shortcuts for ***everything***. I can't really use a Windows keyboard for my Mac, because of this problem.

Here's the Apple keyboard:
[image: Apple keyboard]
And the Windows keyboard:
[image: Windows keyboard]
Are there any third-part keyboards that have the Apple layout?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can actually change the layout of your Windows keyboard. Go to System Preferences, Keyboard, and in the Keyboard tab, you will see a button "Modifier Keys..." Click on it and you can change the external keyboard layout.

For me, I mapped ALT key on external keyboard to Command and the Window key to alt/option, so my external PC keyboard now has the exact same layout as OS X keyboard.

Comment: Cool! Thanks! I will definitely keep this in mind.

Comment: Although this does not directly answer my question, out of all the answers, I have to accept this answer, because it answers the question the best. See [the XY problem](http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/questions/527/how-to-address-the-xy-problem-in-this-question-and-a-potential-problem-with-one). Please continue posting answers, but this is the best answer for my situation.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there are several companies producing keyboards with Maclayout, e.g. Logitech: http://reviews.logitech.com/7061/4741/logitech-dinovo-keyboard-mac-edition-reviews/reviews.htm, and also Keysonic: http://www.computerbild.de/artikel/cb-News-PC-Hardware-Keysonic-ACK-540-MAC-RF-Spezialtastatur-fuer-Apple-Rechner-3364609.html

Answer (score 2):

There are many. Here are a few.

### [Matias Keyboards](http://matias.ca/)

### [MacAlly Keyboards](http://www.macally.com/EN/Product/inputkeymouse.asp)

### [Happy Hacking Keyboard Lite 2](http://www.pfusystems.com/hhkeyboard/hhkeyboard.html)

Kensington, Adesso and Logitech also offer keyboards for Mac, or keyboards you can adapt to use on a Mac. You can use any Windows-style keyboard with a Mac. You just remap the command and option keys.

I've never liked Apple's keyboards or mice, and I've been using third-party replacements on my Macs since the early 1990s.

Here's the [list of dozens of third-party keyboards for sale at MacMall](http://www.macmall.com/n/Keyboards-Keypads/macMainMenu-235187712).

Answer (score 2):

If you like old school "clicky" keyboards:

[daskeyboard Model S Professional For Mac](http://www.daskeyboard.com/model-s-professional-for-mac/)

[Unicomp Spacesaver M](http://pckeyboard.com/mm5/merchant.mvc?Store_Code=PCK&Screen=CTGY&Category_Code=SpacesaverM)

Answer (score 1):

Razer has a Mac-layout of their BlackWidow mechanical keyboard.

http://store.razerzone.com/store/razerusa/en_US/pd/productID.211324200

Beyond that, it's fairly easy to remap the keys (which is what I've done) so they obey your Apple-created muscle memory.

Comment: Can you include a link please?

Answer (score -1):

The [happy hacking brand keyboards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Happy_Hacking_Keyboard) are made with Apple's OS X in mind.